# How to send blobfile using NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to send a blobfile using NestJS, it is my first time using Nodejs. I read a lot of articles, but couldn't solve my problem.

```
@Get('/api/font/blob1')
@Header('Content-type', 'font/woff')
async fontBlob1(@Query('text') text, @Query('fontNo') fontNo): Promise<unknown> {
    let font = await this.appService.fontBlob(text, fontNo);
    console.info('blog')
    console.info(font)
    return font['data'];
}

async fontBlob(text, fontNo) {
    let srcFont = '~/font/official/' + fontNo + '.woff';
    let fontmin = new Fontmin()
        .src(srcFont)
        .use(Fontmin.glyph({
            text: text,
            hinting: false
        })).use(Fontmin.ttf2woff());

    const font = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fontmin.run((error, files) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(files[0].contents);
        });
    });

    console.info('blob service finish')
    console.info(font)
    return font;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use NestJs 8 you can see the documentation [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files#streaming-files)

Else you can use the decorator `@Res()` Which gives you an instance of the server response.

Example :

```js
@Get('/api/font/blob1')
@Header('Content-type', 'font/woff')
async fontBlob1(
   @Query('text') text,
   @Query('fontNo') fontNo,
   @Res() res,
): Promise<void> {
     let font: Buffer = await this.appService.fontBlob(text, fontNo);
     const stream = new Readable();

     stream.push(font.buffer);
     stream.push(null);
     stream.pipe(res);
}
```

if you use **Fastify Nest application** you can proceed like this :

```js
@Get('/api/font/blob1')
@Header('Content-type', 'font/woff')
async fontBlob1(
    @Query('text') text, 
    @Query('fontNo') fontNo, 
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: FastifyReply // <= Type from fastify
): Promise<void> {
     try {
       let font: Buffer = await this.appService.fontBlob(text, fontNo);
       response.send(file);
     } catch (error) {
       res.removeHeader('Content-type');
       res.removeHeader('Content-disposition');
       res.status(error.status).send(error);
     }
}
```